# Why isn't this GEORADIUS call on redis working?

Tags: redis, geolocation, geospatial

1. Add x to mytest

   ```
   127.0.0.1:6379> geoadd mytest -78.45 38.13 x
   (integer) 1
   ```
2. Try to find points within 50.000km of x:

   ```
   127.0.0.1:6379> georadius mytest 72.8 19.13 50000 km
   (empty list or set)
   ```
3. Add y to mytest:

   ```
   127.0.0.1:6379> geoadd mytest 72.8 19.13 y
   (integer) 1
   ```
4. Calculate distance between x and y:

   ```
   127.0.0.1:6379> geodist mytest x y km
   "12979.3623"
   ```

Why is (2) an empty set if (4) finds the distance between x and y to be of only 12979 km?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a defect - I recommend that you report it by opening an issue at http://github.com/antirez/redis/issues.

Interestingly, note that:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> GEORADIUS mytest -78.45 38.13 50000 km
1) "x"
2) "y"
```

And also:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> GEORADIUSBYMEMBER mytest y 50000 km
1) "y"
127.0.0.1:6379> GEORADIUSBYMEMBER mytest x 50000 km
1) "x"
2) "y"
```

Comment: Bug fixed @ redis repo.